# CherryPy timeout error while trying to train ML model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cherrypy

I am training an ML [pipeline] model on a linux server [RHEL] using linux screen util, the model training is initiated by a HTTP post which contain a few configuration parameters etc... Occasionally the model training takes a lot of time 2 hours plus... and the cherrypy server that received the configuration parameters for the ML model closes down due to time out.

The trouble is...

After the successful training there is a bunch of data/ log messages being processed, all of which stop/fail when the cherrypy server times out.. while waiting for a message from the ML training code

how do I fix this..?

I have tried extending the session timeout, but there are data sets that might take more time to train with, than the max limit

```py
screen_process = startLinuxScreenProcess(scrn_name, os.path.join(script_path, 'model_trainer'), engn, classifier)
```

startLinuxScreenProcess-> uses python's subprocess module to run the command
The model_trainer.py upon completion returns success fail message along with accuracy figures and a few other model details [name/ input params] which are stored on a mongoDB later on

Is the Idea of using CherryPy this way.. flawed to start with..?

How do you handle long wait times between the model training and the subsequent logging..?

Comment: When you say "the cherrypy server [...] closes down due to time out", do you mean the actual Python process stops, or that the request times out?

Comment: the request times out... because the python process is still going on... and didnt return anything to the cherrypy server

Comment: The best thing to do is to run that process in the background, returning the task id immediately and then polling for the status in a loop (probably with exponential backoff) with extra client requests. You can use smth like RQ or Celery, or write your own plugin if you want to keep it inside of the CherryPy architecture.